# Add buttons next to the definition list items

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

I have the following definition list set up:

```
<dl class="details">
    <dt>Name:</dt>
    <dd>John Doe</dd>
    <dt>Title:</dt>
    <dd>Engineer</dd>
 </dl>
```

Here is the js fiddle which has the css :

http://jsfiddle.net/WCBBc/11/

Now I need to add an edit and delete button next to the dt with some additional spacing, so it should look like:

Name: John Doe Edit Delete

Tile: Engineer Edit Delete

I am not sure how to do without adding some hacky classes.

Comment: how are you planning to add the buttons? jquery?

Comment: just plain css if it's possible.

Comment: But you need dom elements in order to put buttons because pseudo-elements like `:before`, `:after` are not selectable by javascript. How are you going to trigger these buttons?

Comment: Why not just use a table, or even a ul/ol? "dl" is for definition list so using them here doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: I am thinking about possible alternatives now. But i was wondering if it was doable with dl/dt

Comment: If you don't want to change your html you can add dom elements with jQuery.

Comment: @Micheal Usually if you can't see a clean simple way to structure your html your using the wrong elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I changed the css on your dd and dt rules to make it display: inline-block and remove the floats. Then I added a button class which also displays inline-block and added the buttons directly on the dd after the information you had there.

http://jsfiddle.net/LTvTE/

```
<dl class="details">
    <dt>Name:</dt>
    <dd>John Doe <button class="edit button">Edit</button></dd>
    <dt>Title:</dt>
    <dd>Engineer<button class="edit button">Edit</button></dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 1):

**append them**

```
$('.details dd').each(function() {//for each dd
    $(this).append('<button>edit</button><button>delete</button>');//add buttons
});
```

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/X6pyK/

Comment: Seemed like an appropriate answer. though it should probably just be part of the template these are generated from instead of being added after the fact, unless there a reason it's not.

Comment: I like this answer but I do not require the edit delete on every dd, and also at some point i might have to name a different label for a some dd. So at this point Evan's answer suits me.

Comment: That's awesome. I definitely didn't think this question was about how to just add a button tag in html, but I'm glad that you got an answer that works.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Links are bad for this type of thing: [Look Here](http://37signals.com/svn/archives2/google_web_accelerator_hey_not_so_fast_an_alert_for_web_app_designers.php)

Use buttons instead. THat said:

```
<dl class="details">
<dt>Name:</dt>
<dd>John Doe&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<a href='edit'>edit</a>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<a href='delete'>delete</a></dd>
<dt>Title:</dt>
<dd>Engineer&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<a href='edit'>edit</a>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<a href='delete'>delete</a></dd>
```

Comment: "Links are bad for this type of thing" ...but you're using links and not buttons!

Comment: @otinanai i don't mean links are bad in general. They're great, in fact. Just don't use them when you're touching data.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with putting a button in your markup.

```
<dl class="details">
    <dt>Name:</dt>
    <dd>John Doe <button>moo</button></dd>
    <dt>Title:</dt>
    <dd>Engineer <button>moo</button></dd>
</dl>
```

then:

```
button {float:right}
```